# Map.Entry<> java

Tags: java, c++, blockchain

I have no idea about java whatsoever but I found this blockchain guide in java and I have been trying to understand and convert the code in C++ (my thing). I was doing good so far but I am stuck here. I cant understand this for loop and Map.Entry<> thing. Any kind of help is appreciated.

And also I am new to blockchain.
The link to this guide is:
https://medium.com/programmers-blockchain/creating-your-first-blockchain-with-java-part-2-transactions-2cdac335e0ce

If that helps.

Here is the code:

```
public class Wallet {
public PrivateKey privateKey;
public PublicKey publicKey; 
public HashMap<String,TransactionOutput> UTXOs = new HashMap<String,TransactionOutput>();
public float getBalance() {
    float total = 0;    
    for (Map.Entry<String, TransactionOutput> item: NoobChain.UTXOs.entrySet()){
        TransactionOutput UTXO = item.getValue();
        if(UTXO.isMine(publicKey)) { //if output belongs to me ( if coins belong to me )
            UTXOs.put(UTXO.id,UTXO); //add it to our list of unspent transactions.
            total += UTXO.value ; 
        }
    }  
    return total;
}
```

What is this for loop doing is beyond me. If anyone could provide a simpler C++ version of this loop.

Comment: C++ has templates, which are characterized by `Type<AnotherType>`, and foreach syntax (`for (Type variable : anotherVariable)`). So, it's unclear what you don't understand about it.

Comment: The java Map internaly has Entries. In your case you iterate over the entry set.

Comment: Would you understand `for (std::map<string, transaction_output>::value_type item : NoobChain.UTXOs) { ... }` syntax (note that there are much better ways to write this for in C++, it's just the closes one)?

Comment: It's just a key-value pair. For each key-value pair in the `NoobChain.UTXOs`, if the transaction is mine, add it to this wallet's list of UTXOs and increment the total.

Comment: An entry is a key/value pair. You can find that easier and faster on the web. The other concepts used (loops and conditions) exists in C++

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just providing a C++ code snipped let me try to explain this:
In java there are data structures called Maps which contain key-value pairs (you probably could guess this part). The Map itself is not iterable, so in order to loop through a map you can loop through all its keys (also called a key set), all the values or all the key-value pairs (also know as the Entry set). The latter happens in your example.
So in your example you have a map of String (the keys) and TransactionOutput objects (values). The for, loops through these pairs and each pair is stored in the variable item. Then the value part is extracted from the key-value pair (item) which is a TransactionOutput object.
Then this object is verified with the method isMine() and if that is true, it is added to another Map (calles UTXOs) that maps Strings (the key) to TransactionOutput object. In this case it seems the string (the key in the map) is the id of the TransactionObject.
The variable total is increased by the value of the added TrasactionOutput.

Side note: This for-loop could as well just loop through all the values in the map since the key is never used in this particular loop.

Now, to explain this in other words, it is going through the map of TransactionOutputs, the ones that belong to "me" are put aside in a separate map and the total amount of the TrasactionOutput values that belong to "me" is returned.

Hope this clears things up!
Good luck,
Teo

Comment: hey thanks a lot brother.. could also tell me what is this entrySet() function doing?

Comment: Hey, no problrm, glad to help. If you find the answer helpful don't forget to vote up. The entrySet() returns a Set (collection with no dublicate elements) of key-value pairs from the map.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--